# Working UIButton animations in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uibutton

I've been trying to get this snippit of code to work but I can't seem to get my UIButton to animate through images.

```
@IBOutlet weak var screenButton: UIButton!;

func animation(){
        var animationButton : UIButton!; 
        var imageList = [UIImage]();
        var image1:UIImage = UIImage(named:"3fingers-o-l-animation1.png")!;
        var image2:UIImage = UIImage(named:"4fingers-o-l-animation1.png")!;

        animationButtonscreenButton = screenButton;
        imageList = [image1, image2];

        animationButton!.imageView!.animationImages = imageList;
        animationButton!.imageView!.animationDuration = 1.0;
        animationButton!.imageView!.startAnimating();
    }
```

After writing this code I've dragged a line from screenButton to the button I want to animate through the image in the Storyboard.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: UIButton is not initialized...

Comment: And that's why you should use `?` and `!` when appropriate. Don't `?` all the code, because it will hide bugs. If something is supposed to be there use a force unwrap `!`. Or in this case just a non-optional variable. You would have seen the problem very early.

Comment: i) initialize UIButton ii)set it's frame iii) addSubview on your view

Comment: I've tried your suggestions and I still cannot get it to work. I've edited my question with what I've done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is to not re-initialize the `UIButton` in the function `animation`; so, comment out this line:

```
//var animationButton : UIButton!
```

Besides just having an `IBOutlet`, we need also an `IBAction` to your function `animation`. Do the same thing as you do for your button by control dragging a "line" to the block of function (check `IBAction`, not `IBOutlet`).

***A little walk-through while you are still in storyboard:***

---

- What you have is only one button named: `animationButton`, which is an `IBOutlet` from your storyboard to your code by control-dragging a "line".
- For your `animation` function: 
  Control-drag also from storyboard from the button a "line" to the block of the `animation` function.
- Set up an initial image for you button in storyboard as will be mentioned shortly below.

---

In addition, we need to set up an initial image in storyboard; otherwise, the image property of the button is `nil`.

Please do so in storyboard by clicking on the right hand side "Attributes Inspector" and then set an image where it says "image". As test, I set that up as "1.jpg".

Thus, you code should look like the following:

```
@IBOutlet weak var animationButton: UIButton!
@IBAction func animation()
{
    print("button touched")
    //var animationButton : UIButton!
    var imageList = [UIImage]()
    var image1:UIImage = UIImage(named:"1.jpg")!
    var image2:UIImage = UIImage(named:"2.jpg")!

    //animationButtonscreenButton = screenButton;
    imageList = [image1, image2];

    animationButton!.imageView!.animationImages = imageList
    animationButton!.imageView!.animationDuration = 1.0
    animationButton!.imageView!.startAnimating()
}
```

Just ran a quick test; it gets touch event and the images animate on the button. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you. When reading through your answer I found out what what was wrong with my code. The image property of my buttons was nil. Placing an image in that field fixed my problem and my screen is now animating like crazy!